# Memoise an Rcpp function?

Tags: r, performance, recursion, rcpp, memoization

I have written a recursive function in R and used memoise to speed it up.  I have tried to speed it up further by writing it in Rcpp and then memoising the Rcpp function, but the R function is faster.  Why is this, and is there any way to speed this up in my usage?

```
require(microbenchmark)
require(Rcpp)
require(memoise)
```

Rcpp function:

```
cppFunction('
double FunCpp (unsigned int i, double d1, double d2, 
                double p, double s, unsigned int imax, 
                double n, double k, double r, 
                double m, double t) {

  if (i == 0) return 0;
  if (i == 1) return log2(-1*d1);
  if (i == 2) return log2(d2*d1 - p*s);

  double x = log2(fabs(-(((imax - (n - i))/imax)*k*r + m + (n - i)*t)));
  x = x + FunCpp(i-1, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

  double y = log2((n - i + 1)*t*k*r*((imax - ((n - i + 1) - 1))/imax));
  y = y + FunCpp(i-2, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

  return x + log2(1 - pow(2,y-x));
}
')
FunCpp = memoise(FunCpp)
```

R function:

```
FunR = memoise(function(i, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t) {

  if(i == 0) 0
  else if(i == 1) log2(-1*d1)
  else if(i == 2) log2(d2*d1 - p*s)
  else {
    x = log2(abs(-(((imax - (n - i))/imax)*k*r + m + (n - i)*t)))
    x = x + FunR(i-1, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t)

    y = log2((n - i + 1)*t*k*r*((imax - ((n - i + 1) - 1))/imax))
    y = y + FunR(i-2, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t)  

    x + log2(1 - 2^(y-x))
  }
})
```

This speed comparison is realistic for my purposes.  The recursive function is used on a range of integers, but afterward, it won't be called with the same inputs again.  So for speed comparison, here I'm calling the functions from within other functions, and after I'm done calling the recursive functions I use forget() to reset the cache.

```
TestFunR = function() {
  x = sapply(1:31, function(i) {
    FunR(i = 31-i, d1 = -152, d2 = -147.33, p = 150, s = 0.03, 
         imax = 30, n = 31, k = 1, r = 1, m = 2, t = 5)
  })
  forget(FunR)
}

TestFunCpp = function() {
  x = sapply(1:31, function(i) {
    FunCpp(i = 31-i, d1 = -152, d2 = -147.33, p = 150, s = 0.03, 
           imax = 30, n = 31, k = 1, r = 1, m = 2, t = 5)
  })
  forget(FunCpp)
}

microbenchmark(TestFunR(), TestFunCpp())


Unit: milliseconds
         expr        min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
   TestFunR()   9.979738  10.4910  12.83228  10.91887  11.89264  61.61513   100  a 
 TestFunCpp() 520.955483 528.6965 547.31103 536.73058 547.66377 729.57631   100   b
```

Edit: I had gotten a method working from Dirk's book prior to posting this.

```
includeText = '
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class F {

  public:
    F(unsigned int n = 200, double d1 = 0, double d2 = 0, double p = 0, double s = 0) {
      memo.resize(n); 
      std::fill( memo.begin(), memo.end(), NAN ); 
      memo[0] = 0;          
      memo[1] = log2(-1*d1);  
      memo[2] = log2(d2*d1 - p*s);
    }

  double FunIL(int i, double d1, double d2, double p, double s, double imax, 
                  double n, double k, double r, double m, double t) {

      if (i < 0) return((double) NAN);
      if (i >= (int) memo.size()) throw std::range_error(\"i too large\");
      if (!std::isnan(memo[i])) return(memo[i]); 

      double x = log2(fabs(-(((imax - (n - i))/imax)*k*r + m + (n - i)*t)));
      x = x + FunIL(i-1, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

      double y = log2((n - i + 1)*t*k*r*((imax - ((n - i + 1) - 1))/imax));
      y = y + FunIL(i-2, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

      memo[i] = x + log2(1 - pow(2,y-x));
      return(memo[i]); 
    }
  private:
    std::vector< double > memo; 
};
'
bodyText = '
  int is = Rcpp::as<int>(i);
  double d1s = Rcpp::as<double>(d1);
  double d2s = Rcpp::as<double>(d2);
  double ps = Rcpp::as<double>(p);
  double ss = Rcpp::as<double>(s);
  double imaxs = Rcpp::as<double>(imax);
  double ns = Rcpp::as<double>(n);
  double ks = Rcpp::as<double>(k);
  double rs = Rcpp::as<double>(r);
  double ms = Rcpp::as<double>(m);
  double ts = Rcpp::as<double>(t);
  F f(ns, d1s, d2s, ps, ss);
  return Rcpp::wrap( f.FunIL(is, d1s, d2s, ps, ss, imaxs, ns, ks, rs, ms, ts) );
'

FunInline = cxxfunction(signature(i = "integer", d1 = "numeric", d2 = "numeric", p = "numeric",
                                  s = "numeric", imax = "numeric", n = "numeric", k = "numeric",
                                  r = "numeric", m = "numeric", t = "numeric"),
                        plugin = "Rcpp",
                        verbose = T,
                        incl = includeText,
                        body = bodyText)
```

It works equally well (see TestFunInline):

```
microbenchmark(TestFunR(), TestFunCpp(), TestFunCpp_Mem(), TestFunInline())
Unit: microseconds
             expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval cld
       TestFunR()   8871.251   9067.758  10301.8003   9287.5725   9593.1310  19270.081   100  b 
     TestFunCpp() 514415.356 517160.251 522431.2980 519321.6130 523811.7640 584812.731   100   c
 TestFunCpp_Mem()    245.474    264.291    284.8908    281.6105    292.0885    526.870   100 a  
  TestFunInline()    279.686    295.723    378.2134    306.8425    316.0370   6621.364   100 a
```

However, I couldn't get it to work with doParallel.  I'm optimizing an objective function on each process using the optim and optimx packages, and when I use %do% it works, but when I use %dopar% all I see is that the objective function cannot be evaluated at the initial parameters.  I took Dirk's advice from his many other posts and put Coatless's method into a package, but I'm not sure about how to put the method from Dirk's book into a package.  It's just my inexperience in C++.

Edit 2: It finally clicked how to put Dirk's method in a source file in my package.  I know there are other discussions about using Rcpp with doParallel, but I'm putting this code here because it is another good way to solve my problem, and by adding this code to a source file in my package, it happened to be much easier for me to get this to work in my parallel approach than inline was.

```
class F {

  public:
    F(unsigned int n = 200, double d1 = 0, double d2 = 0, double p = 0, double s = 0) {
      memo.resize(n); 
      std::fill( memo.begin(), memo.end(), NAN ); 
      memo[0] = 0;          
      memo[1] = log2(-1*d1);  
      memo[2] = log2(d2*d1 - p*s);
    }

    double FunIL(int i, double d1, double d2, double p, double s, double imax, 
      double n, double k, double r, double m, double t) {

      if (i < 0) return((double) NAN);
      if (i >= (int) memo.size()) throw std::range_error("\"i too large\"");
      if (!std::isnan(memo[i])) return(memo[i]); 

      double x = log2(fabs(-(((imax - (n - i))/imax)*k*r + m + (n - i)*t)));
      x = x + FunIL(i-1, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

      double y = log2((n - i + 1)*t*k*r*((imax - ((n - i + 1) - 1))/imax));
      y = y + FunIL(i-2, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

      memo[i] = x + log2(1 - pow(2,y-x));
      return(memo[i]); 
    }
  private:
    std::vector< double > memo; 
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double FunDirk(int i, double d1, double d2, double p, double s, 
                  double imax, double n, double k, double r, 
                  double m, double t) {
    F f(n, d1, d2, p, s);
    return f.FunIL(i, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Memoisize me

Well, first let's think about the purpose of `memoise`. The goal of `memoise` is to **cache function results** and **reuse them**. Thus, after one calculation it no longer needs to recalculate the value again for any other sequence in the computation it can just retrieve the value from the cache. This is particularly relevant for the recursive structure set up.

## `memoise` cache access with respect to R and C++

The setup for memoisize is to cache R value function values. In this case, it is caching those values. However, the C++ code ***cannot*** access the cached values. Thus, the C++ version recalculates each of those values. In essence, you are essentially using:

```
x = sapply(1:31, function(i) {
    FunCpp(i = 31-i, d1 = -152, d2 = -147.33, p = 150, s = 0.03, 
           imax = 30, n = 31, k = 1, r = 1, m = 2, t = 5)
  })
```

## Big O Algo

*Disclaimer: There should be a more formal argument next but its been awhile.*

To understand algorithms, sometimes we need to use what's called [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) that allows us to observe how the code performs asymptotically. Now, the Big O in this case is O(2^N) because of two calls to compute: `Fun(i-1)` and `FunR(i-2)`. However, `memoise` uses a hash map / look up table with probably a Big O of `O(n)` at its worst and `O(1)` at its best. In essence, we have constant vs. exponential asymptotic results.

## Improving Microbenchmarks - W/O Memosizing in C++

However, that does not necessarily mean that the C++ function is garbage. One of the downsides of R to Rcpp and back bridge is the lag time between transferring values between the two domains. Thus, one way we can slightly lower the computation time is by placing the loop completely in C++.

e.g.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector FunCpp_loop(unsigned int e, 
                                double d1, double d2, 
                                double p, double s, unsigned int imax, 
                                double n, double k, double r, 
                                double m, double t){

  Rcpp::NumericVector o(e);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < e; i++){

    o(i) = FunCpp(31-(i+1), -152, -147.33, 150, 0.03, 30, 31, 1, 1, 2, 5);

  }

  return o;
}
```

However, the benchmarks here do not really improve the situation (even by pre-creating the vector `1:31`)

```
Unit: milliseconds
              expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
      TestFunR(tv)   8.467568   9.077262   9.986837   9.449952  10.60555  14.91243   100
    TestFunCpp(tv) 476.678391 482.489094 487.687811 486.351087 490.25346 579.38161   100
 TestFunCpp_loop() 478.348070 482.588307 488.234200 486.211347 492.33965 521.10918   100
```

## Memoziation in C++

We can apply the same memoziation techniques given in `memoise` in C++. The implementation is not as pretty and nice but it serves to show the same principles are applicable.

To start, we'll make a hashmap.

```
// Memoization structure to hold the hash map
struct mem_map{

  // Initializer to create the static (presistent) map
  static std::map<int, double> create_map()
  {
    std::map<int, double> m;
    m.clear();
    return m;
  }

  // Name of the static map for the class
  static std::map<int, double> memo;

};

// Actuall instantiate the class in the global scope (I know, bad me...)
std::map<int, double> mem_map::memo =  mem_map::create_map();
```

Now, we probably should make some accessors to work with the map object.

```
// Reset the map
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void clear_mem(){
  mem_map::memo.clear();
}

// Get the values of the map.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::map<int, double> get_mem(){
  return mem_map::memo;
}
```

Lastly, let's change around some internal things in your function.

```
// Users function
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double FunCpp_Mem (int i, double d1, double d2, 
                   double p, double s, unsigned int imax, 
                   double n, double k, double r, 
                   double m, double t) {

  // We have already computed the value...
  if(mem_map::memo.count(i) > 0)
    return mem_map::memo[i];


  // Otherwise, let us get ready to compute it!
  double res = 0; 

  if (i <= 2){ 
    if (i <= 0) { // i == 1 
      res = 0.0;
    }else if (i == 1) {
      res = log2(-1.0*d1);
    }else { // i == 2
      res = log2(d2*d1 - p*s);
    }

    // Store result in hashmap
    mem_map::memo[i] = res;

    return res;
  }

  // Calculate if not in special case.

  double x = log2(fabs(-(((imax - (n - i))/imax)*k*r + m + (n - i)*t)));
  x = x + FunCpp_Mem(i-1, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);

  double y = log2((n - i + 1)*t*k*r*((imax - ((n - i + 1) - 1))/imax));
  y = y + FunCpp_Mem(i-2, d1, d2, p, s, imax, n, k, r, m, t);


  res = x + log2(1 - pow(2,y-x));


  // Update the hashmap for uncalculated value
  mem_map::memo[i] = res;

  return res;
}
```

*Whew* Lots of work. Let's test it out to see if it was worth it.

```
# Benchmark for Rcpp Memoization
TestFunCpp_mem = function(tv) {
  x = sapply(tv, function(i) {
    FunCpp_Mem(i = 31-i, d1 = -152, d2 = -147.33, p = 150, s = 0.03, 
               imax = 30, n = 31, k = 1, r = 1, m = 2, t = 5)
  })
  clear_mem()
}

TestFunR = function(tv) {
  x = sapply(tv, function(i) {
    FunR(i = 31-i, d1 = -152, d2 = -147.33, p = 150, s = 0.03, 
         imax = 30, n = 31, k = 1, r = 1, m = 2, t = 5)
  })
  forget(FunR)
}

# Pre-generate vector
tv = 1:31

microbenchmark(TestFunR(tv),TestFunCpp_mem(tv))
```

And the results....

```
microbenchmark(TestFunR(tv),TestFunCpp_mem(tv))
Unit: microseconds
               expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
       TestFunR(tv) 8246.324 8662.694 9345.6947 9009.868 9797.126 13001.995   100
 TestFunCpp_mem(tv)  203.832  214.939  253.7931  228.898  240.906  1277.325   100
```

The Cpp Function with memoization is about 40.5x faster than the R version! Memoization was **definitely** worth it!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the code and full explanation.  It works beautifully!  I'm using this for optimizing model parameters and this is giving me a nice speed-up.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nicely done. For what it is worth, I also discuss memoization including doing it in C++ in the introductory chapter of the Rcpp book, using the recursive Fibonacci sequence as the running example that is to be optimised.

Comment: Hi Dirk, please see my edit about the method from your book.  Thanks.

Comment: @BenErnest the main goal of this answer was to highlight why `memoise` was not working under *serial* structure (e.g. not *parallel*). Please please create a new question if there is an issue with the parallelization. (I expect there to be...)

Comment: @Coatless point taken.  I was responding to Dirk saying that his method worked great too, but yours was initially easier for me to implement in my parallel approach because your code worked as-is in my source file.  After thinking some more, it became clear how to add Dirk's method to my source file, so I added it to my post.  The point is that both methods work great, and because they're in a source file in a package, they also happen to be easy to implement with doParallel.  Thanks again, you've really helped me to understand what I'm doing better.